# How to pass value from tcomb-form-native to reducer? React + redux

Tags: javascript, validation, react-native, redux, tcomb-form-native

In my project I'm using `tcomb-form-native` library to validation a form. Redux working fine but I can't pass value of inputs to reducer. I have to do this, because I want to create array with data from fields.

How can I pass values of my inputs to reducer? 
Or maybe it's not possible with this library and I have to use another one?

Form.js

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      closeExpenseDialog: (value) => dispatch({type: 'CLOSE_EXPENSE_DIALOG'}),
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      value: state.closeExpenseDialog.value,
  };
};


const Form = t.form.Form;

const Expense = t.struct({
  expense: t.String,
  cost: t.Number
});

const options = {
  fields: {
    expense: {
      error: 'This field is required'
    },
    cost: {
      error: 'This field is required'
    }
  }
};

handleClick = () => {
    const value = this._form.getValue();
    if (value) {
      console.log(value);
      this.props.closeExpenseDialog(value);
    } else {
      console.log('validation failed');
    }
  }

  <Form 
   type={Expense}
   ref={c => this.props._form = c}
   options={options} 
   value={this.props.value}
  />
  <ActionButton
   onPress={this.props.closeExpenseDialog}
   title={title}
  />
```

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    value: {}
};
const mainReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) { 
   case 'CLOSE_EXPENSE_DIALOG':
     console.log('it works')
     console.log(state.value) //undefined
   default:
     return state;
   }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed add `onChange()` attribute and use it to pass object `value` to the Reducer.

Form.js

```
const Expense = t.struct({
  expense: t.String,
  cost: t.Number
});

const options = {
   fields: {
    expense: {
      error: 'This field is required'
    },
    cost: {
      error: 'This field is required'
   }
 }
};

handleClick = () => {
   const value = this._form.getValue();
    if (value) {
  this.props.submitExpenseDialog();
 } 
}

<Form 
 type={Expense}
 ref={c => this._form = c}
 options={options} 
 value={this.props.value}
 onChange={this.props.changeExpenseInputs}
/>
<ActionButton
 onPress={this.handleClick}
 title={title}
/>
```

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    value: {}
};
const mainReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) { 
   case 'SUBMIT_EXPENSE_DIALOG':
     console.log(state.value)
   default:
     return state;
 }
};
```